# How can iI get the current path and not the path of exe in c#?

Tags: c#, path, console-application

I publish a `console project` in `C#` and I put it in the `path environment` FE `c:\some\path\project.exe`. the excecutable has the following code.

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
Console.WriteLine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory);
Console.WriteLine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName));
```

When I execute it. in the cmd I Get the following:

```
c:\here\here\here > project.exe

c:\some\path\project.dll
c:\some\path\
c:\some\path\
c:\some\path
c:\some\path
```

I need to get the path `c:\here\here\here`

Comment: I think what you want is `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this besides what was suggested in Dharati's answer:

```
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
string noFileNamePath = fullPath.Substring(0, (fullPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```